# Getting warning "Prop `htmlFor` did not match" when using useId() hook inside forwardRef component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The following component is rendered in a NextJS `13.4.2` application, using App Router and React `18.2.0`. When rendering the page, I get :

> Warning: Prop `htmlFor` did not match. Server: ":Rqd6qqcq:" Client: ":R39krb9j9:"

I use `useId` in other components but this warning is issued when using `forwardRef`. What could be the cause of this issue, and how to resolve it?

```
"use client";
import React, { forwardRef, useId } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

type InputRenderProps<E> = E extends HTMLTextAreaElement
  ? React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<E>
  : E extends HTMLSelectElement
  ? React.SelectHTMLAttributes<E>
  : React.InputHTMLAttributes<E>;

export type InputProps = {
  id?: string;
  className?: string;
  label?: React.ReactNode | null;
  message?: React.ReactNode | null;
  dirty?: boolean | null;
  status?: "success" | "warning" | "error" | "default" | null;
  renderInput: <E extends HTMLElement>(
    props: InputRenderProps<E>
  ) => React.ReactNode;
};

const Input = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, InputProps>(
  (
    {
      id,
      className,
      label,
      message,
      dirty,
      status = "default",
      renderInput,
    }: InputProps,
    ref
  ) => {
    const inputId = useId();

    return (
      <div ref={ref} id={id} className={classNames("form-control", className)}>
        {label ? (
          <label className="label" htmlFor={inputId}>
            <span className="label-text text-inherit">{label}</span>
            {dirty ? <PencilIcon size={16} /> : null}
          </label>
        ) : null}
        {renderInput({
          id: inputId,
          className: classNames(
            "input input-bordered bg-base-300 placeholder:italic placeholder:opacity-50",
            {
              "input-ghost": status === "default",
              "input-error": status === "error",
              "input-success": status === "success",
              "input-warning": status === "warning",
            }
          ),
        })}
        {message ? (
          <label className="label" htmlFor={inputId}>
            <span
              className={classNames("label-text-alt", {
                "text-error": status === "error",
                "text-success": status === "success",
                "text-warning": status === "warning",
              })}
            >
              {message}
            </span>
          </label>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Input;
```

Comment: This is just a wild guess but maybe the forwardRef messes with the useID?

Comment: Interesting. `forwardRef` does mess with `useId`. :(

Comment: i dont get any error if i call it like that

```ts
'use client'
import Input from "../components/Input";

const TestPage = () => {
    return <div><Input renderInput={({id}) => <div id={id}>test</div>}></Input></div>;
    }

export default TestPage;
```